# Reseed identity column in other database (not in database which is currently in use)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to reseed identity column in a table, but not in the database which is currently in use.

This works:

```
use database;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table', reseed, 0);
```

But, I want to do something like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (database.[dbo].table, reseed, 0); -- works not
```

Comment: Works not? Practicing your Yoda? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
EXEC database.sys.sp_executesql N'DBCC CHECKIDENT(N''dbo.table'', reseed, 0);';
```

Or even:

```
DECLARE @t nvarchar(513) = N'dbo.table';

EXEC database.sys.sp_executesql 
   N'DBCC CHECKIDENT(@t, reseed, 0);', 
   N'@t nvarchar(513)', @t;
```

Also, if the table is empty *and does not have any FK references or other limitations*, you can do this easier using...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE database.dbo.table;
```

...which happens to also reseed the `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: can't truncate - table is referenced by foreign key. exec database..sp_execeutesql - getting error Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: @davor Sorry, I didn't enclose the table in single quotes. You should update your question, since I merely grabbed your syntax. :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about using EXEC to execute the USE and CHECKIDENT?

```
EXEC('USE database;DBCC CHECKIDENT (''dbo.table'', reseed, 0);')
```