# Resetting Primary key without deleting truncating table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, primary-key

I have a table with a primary key, now without any reason I don't know when I am inserting data it is being loaded like this

```
Pk_Col Some_Other_Col
1           A
2           B
3           C
1002        D
1003        E
1901        F
```

Is there any way I can reset my table like below, without deleting/ truncating the table?

```
Pk_Col Some_Other_Col
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
5           E
6           F
```

Comment: If you care about the *numeric* value of an Identity column (which is what you're actually asking about. The concept of Primary Key is orthogonal to the concept of the identity column), you're using them wrong. You should treat it as an opaque blob that *happens* to fit in a numeric column. You shouldn't be showing these values to anyone, and so it should not matter what *actual* value is assigned.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever put that as an answer. You'll get a +1 from me!

Comment: I ain't sure if I missed the point but my primary key is actually a identity column starts with 1 and seed 1. I have not yet linked it to any other foreign key. But I don't want to delete the table or data for two reason 1: Data size 2: Even if i delete and in next insert this thing again happened then I won't be able to delete my table/data

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite the point he's making is if this is an identity column than the values are arbitrary and it doesn't matter what the value is. 1,2,3,7 what's the difference it doesn't matter if there are gaps and **GAPS WILL HAPPEN** so don't worry about it.

Comment: The first part of my point is that what you're really talking about is the Identity column in your table. Yes, it may happen to be the PK for this table, but when you're talking about automatic numbering, you're talking about the Identity column. It is possible to have tables where the Identity column and the PK column(s) are not the same at all.

Comment: @Zane and @ Damien_The_Unveliever Thanks for clarifying it. but I would like to keep this question open for a while to see if we get more answers to it. :) Thanks again and +1 to you both.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite if you [must](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15574799/1532495)

Comment: The whole point of an `identity` column is that it can be non-sequential. This is because the database handles things like concurrent writes/rollbacks etc. for you automatically behind the scenes.  Part of this will involve having "gaps" in your sequence. If you don't want gaps, don't use an `identity` but also be prepared for terrible performance and tons of issues if you try to make your own solution.

Comment: @Zane May I request you to post that as an answer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reseed identity column in other database (not in database which is currently in use)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574757/reseed-identity-column-in-other-database-not-in-database-which-is-currently-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the IDENTITY column so DELETE/INSERT is the only way. You can reseed the IDENTITY column and recreate the data, like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.tbl',RESEED,0);    
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (Some_Other_Col)
SELECT Some_Other_Col
FROM (DELETE FROM tbl OUTPUT deleted.*) d;
```

That assumes there are no foreign keys referencing this data.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, *really* want to have neat identity values you can write a cursor (slow but maintainable) or investigate any number of "how can I find gaps in my sequence" question on SO and perform an `UPDATE` accordingly (runs faster but tricky to get right).  This becomes exponentially harder when you start having foreign keys pointing back to this table.  Be prepared to re-run this script any time data is put into, or removed from this table.

**Edit**: `IDENTITY` columns cannot be updated *per se*.  You can, however, `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON;`, `INSERT` a row with the desired `IDENTITY` value and the values from the other columns of an existing row, then `DELETE` the existing row.  The nett effect on the data being the same as an `UPDATE`.

The only sensible reason to do this is if your table has about two billion rows and you're about to run out of integers for your identity column.  If that's the case you have a whole world of other stuff to worry about, too.

But seriously - listen to @Damien, don't worry about it.

Comment: IF you're running out of integers at 2 billion then you're forgetting about negatives `;-)`. Reseed your identity at 0 with a step of -1.

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect. Unfortunately you cannot UPDATE an IDENTITY column in SQL Server. If you could then there would be easier and more efficient ways to do it without using a cursor.

Comment: @gvee - most people do forget about negatives.  Have you *ever* seen the statement `CREATE TABLE dbo.XYZ(ID int IDENTITY(-2147483648, 1) ...`?  I haven't.

Comment: @MichaelGreen I have! `;-)` Far more efficient than the usual change to using a `bigint`.

Comment: Using negative is only if you didn't select unsigned, then you accidentally have twice as much space now (than what you "thought"), but if you DID choose unsigned, you can NOT gain more space going negative for 2 reasons, one, it is unsigned, you actually can't add the '-', second, it is the same space either way, as with a "Tinyint", The signed range is -128 to 127. The unsigned range is 0 to 255, you still only are allowed 256 slots either way.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE #temp1
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Id

ALTER TABLE #temp1
DROP COLUMN Id

ALTER TABLE #temp1
ADD  Id int identity(1,1)
```

Try this one.

Comment: Please don't do this. It's unnecessary there is almost no reason to re-seed a key value.