# MySQL: How to correctly set foreign key values in mapping tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Let's say I have three tables with many (<=9999) data rows:

**1.flows table:**

```
flow          flow_id
VARCHAR(6)    1
...           ...
VARCHAR(6)    9999
```

**2.citations table:**

```
citation      citation_id
VARCHAR(20)   1
...           ...
VARCHAR(20)   9999
```

**3.flows_citations (mapping table):**

```
flow_id       citation_id
1             5
...           ...
9999          6348
```

I recently found a question about how to reset `foreign key values` to start `incrementing` from 1 ([Resetting Primary key without deleting truncating table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133151/resetting-primary-key-without-deleting-truncating-table)), and the following answer from Damien_The_Unbeliever has confused me:

**"If you care about the numeric value of an Identity column... you're using them wrong. ... it should not matter what actual value is assigned."**

This may seem like silly question, but isn't it essential that I specify the `values` in the `identity columns` (flow_id and citation_id) in the flows_citations mapping table to refer exactly to the relevant corresponding `values` in the `identity columns` in both the flows and citations tables? If so, then I do need to keep track of these `values`, they are important, and it's helpful to reset them to `increment` from 1 for each data import.

`flow_id` and `citation_id` are both `NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` in the flows and citations tables, and `FOREIGN KEY` in the flows_citations table.

I am currently planning to do this in **Excel** (manually mapping the id values) and then import the data into newly cleared tables (all data rows deleted).

Any guidance/help/clarity on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only concern is that the columns under consideration have the same value. This is because the foreign key is (as name implies) foreign to the table. Thus, numerically, there is no need for incrementing the list. Flip side, page allocation, clustered indexing, and readability,security (natural vs surrogate keys) may or may not be a concern for the columns. Your FACT table is the only one where it might be necessary to remain readable...but not on the database keys that connect them. Lastly, slowly changing dimensions can alter your pk designs... Of course, there are exceptions as you say

Comment: Ran out of room: consider using sequences or a ranking function (if order is not determined by insertion) to add/update the keys. Provides more flexibility in case of failed inserts and also can be hashed. Lastly, page was warning against natural keys (weakens security)

Comment: Thanks clifton_h, greatly appreciate the response. I'll look into sequences and ranking functions, although frankly those words mean little to me at the moment as I'm a beginner to MySQL!!

Comment: Np! I recently obtained my MSCA Querying SOL Server, and what helped was a) finding projects that worked on areas I knew I didn't know, and b) looking up the documentation/professionals to understand how and why something works. Check out [Surrogate Keys - Kimball](http://www.kimballgroup.com/1998/05/surrogate-keys/) for an excellent discussion on what Surrogate keys are and why you might consider them in your tables. Always ask yourself why you are doing something and if your unsure, take the opportunity to learn! Happy coding!